# How to rollback hibernate operation when Exception occured after the operation?

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions, atomic, rollback

I have a java application created using spring+hibernate.

I have a code like this:

```
public class EmployeeDAO extends AbstractHibernateDAO {

    public void save(Employee emp) throws HibernateException {
        super.save(emp);    // inside this method, it calls hibernate session.save(). This super.save method can throws HibernateException
        doSometingElse(emp);    // inside this method, it doesn't call any hibernate methods. It can throws Exception too.
    }   
}
```

I would like to make **EmployeeDAO.save** method as an atomic method in transactional view.

If **super.save(emp)** succeed but **doSomethingElse(emp)** failed (by throwing Exception) then I want the Employee record inserted in **super.save(emp)** be rollbacked.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is annotate the method with `@Transactional` like this:

```
public class EmployeeDAO extends AbstractHibernateDAO {

    @Transactional
    public void save(Employee emp) throws HibernateException {
        super.save(emp);    // inside this method, it calls hibernate session.save(). This super.save method can throws HibernateException
        doSometingElse(emp);    // inside this method, it doesn't call any hibernate methods. It can throws Exception too.
    }   
}
```

That way if an exception is thrown in the EmployeeDAO `save` the whole method worth of hibernate operations will be rolled back.

If you prefer for all the methods in this class to run in their own transaction, then annotate the class `@Transactional` instead.

You'll also need to make sure you do have a transaction manager configured.

If you are using Spring Java configuration you'll want your transaction manager to look something like this:

```
@Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory());
        transactionManager.setDataSource(datasource());
        transactionManager.setJpaDialect(new HibernateJpaDialect());
        return transactionManager;
    }
```

Comment: Somehow I didn't do your suggestion (using @Transactional) and it worked. My transaction manager was configured like this: `<bean id="txManager"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager"> ...`. Do you know how could it work?

Comment: The JPA transaction manager is just a more generic transaction manager. The hibernate 3 one you're using is for Hibernate 3 only. If you were using hibernate 4 you'd use the hibernate 4 transaction manager. [Here's a tutorial](http://blog.springsource.org/2012/04/06/migrating-to-spring-3-1-and-hibernate-4-1/) that shows you how to set them up with Spring. Also, if my answer worked, you should accept it. :)

Comment: Hi, if you read my previous comment, I didn't follow your suggestion at all. It's already working without changing any configuration. I was indeed using hibernate 3. I think it works because of I"m using [`TransactionInterceptor` with key="save"](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-aop-transaction-management-in-hibernate/). Thus method `save` become a transactional implicitly. I'm really sorry that I didn't test the code before asking question. To be fair, I will ask to close this question.